# Is there a way to perform the 'Save Actions' on all files of a project at once?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has this nice feature *'Save Actions'* to perform a bunch of actions, every time a file is saved.

Whenever I change the settings of the '*Save Actions*' I have to touch all files by hand and save them to perform this actions.

E.g. I switched my project to java 7 and activated
`Add missing '@Override' annotations to implementations of interface methods`

When I save a java source, the missing `@Override` annotations are added. But can I trigger eclipse to do this for all files of my project at once?. (Like *Source Format* which can be performed for the hole project via context menu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project (or a package, or a selection of classes, or multiple projects) and choose *Source* > *Clean up...*

Comment: This solution makes the same sort of actions available, but will not automatically run the same actions that were configured in `Project properties` -> `Java Editor` -> `Save Actions`. This runs the actions that are configured in `Project properties` -> `Java Code Style` -> `Clean Up`. For my projects these are not the same (although not intentionally).

Comment: @Martin Pain: you are right. But after setting the configuration for 'Clean Up' to the same actions as in 'Save Actions' it behaves the same.